# Embedding a game in a godaddy website (getcontext error)

Tags: javascript

> This is the code which I am trying to embed on a godaddy website. It works locally on my computer, but when I try to run it on godaddy I get a getcontext error. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I've gotten a bunch of errors with the JS not loading before the HTML, so I had to use a bunch of onload commands.
>
> error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
>       at about:srcdoc:7
>
> > The site is gamingforwater.com if you want to see the actual site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>gamingforwater.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
   <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-5169628706642849" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// load images  

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeNorth = new Image();
var pipeSouth = new Image();

bird.src = "https://shorturl.at/rxZ16";

bg.src = "https://shorturl.at/kwJT4";
fg.src = "https://shorturl.at/lDEMW";
pipeNorth.src = "https://shorturl.at/dpAGI";
pipeSouth.src = "https://shorturl.at/hmp13";


// some variables

var gap = 85;
var constant;

var bX = 10;
var bY = 150;

var gravity = 1.5;

var score = 0;

// on key down

document.addEventListener("keydown",moveUp);

function moveUp(){
    bY -= 25;
}

// pipe coordinates

var pipe = [];

pipe[0] = {
    x : cvs.width,
    y : 0
};

// draw images

function draw(){
    
    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);
    
    
    for(var i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++){
        
        constant = pipeNorth.height+gap;
        ctx.drawImage(pipeNorth,pipe[i].x,pipe[i].y);
        ctx.drawImage(pipeSouth,pipe[i].x,pipe[i].y+constant);
             
        pipe[i].x--;
        
        if( pipe[i].x == 125 ){
            pipe.push({
                x : cvs.width,
                y : Math.floor(Math.random()*pipeNorth.height)-pipeNorth.height
            }); 
        }

        // detect collision
        
        if( bX + bird.width >= pipe[i].x && bX <= pipe[i].x + pipeNorth.width && (bY <= pipe[i].y + pipeNorth.height || bY+bird.height >= pipe[i].y+constant) || bY + bird.height >=  cvs.height - fg.height){
            location.reload(); // reload the page
        }
        
        if(pipe[i].x == 5){
            score++;
        }
        
        
    }

    ctx.drawImage(fg,0,cvs.height - fg.height);
    
    ctx.drawImage(bird,bX,bY);
    
    bY += gravity;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.font = "20px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Score : "+score,10,cvs.height-20);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
}

draw();
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the error is at the line `var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d")` - `cvs` is null because the html is not rendered yet.

I don't know if the embed is inside an iframe, or how much control you have over the contents. But the usual solution might be to put all your javascript (that requires the DOM to be ready) inside a callback:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    // your js here
});
```

Or with jquery:

```
$(function() {
    // your js here
});
```